# How to flip mouse cursor?

Tags: windows-8.1, mouse-cursor

I have switched to left hand mouse on my Windows 8.1 OS, and I feel uncomfortable with the mouse cursor slanting towards the left.
Is there a way to somehow mirror it horizontally so that it will be slanting to the right?

Comment: You used to be able to do it in Win7 by changing the icons for each action but they've retired the project now. Not sure if there's a project for Win8. Here's the WI7 Aero version: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/15833/make-your-mouse-pointers-left-hand-friendly/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download a left-handed cursor set here (bottom of the page): [Left-hand-friendly mouse pointers](https://www.howtogeek.com/15833/make-your-mouse-pointers-left-hand-friendly/)

Change your cursor-theme via Control Panel -> Mouse -> Pointers

Comment: If i click secondary button does the drop down menu shows on the left??

Comment: I doubt it will, as this is something that is not influenced by the shape of your pointer. Have a look here: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/windows-7-application-menus-drop-to-left-instead/2d362701-90e4-4ea6-a3a1-c1391a3d2bea 
You can change handedness in Tablet PC Settings configuration dialog (Even if you do not have a Tablet PC). This does NOT change context menu behaviour in programms such as firefox, just the windows standard one!